# Should trading artifacts for experience always yield an experience gain?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I'm using the "It belongs in a museum!" skill from the Archaeologist skill set to exchange artifacts for experience. I read somewhere that the EXP gain is equal to the item's (selling) value.

A few times, I have enchanted some items at the Anvil of Krong and used the skill on it. Most of the time it worked okay, but in one case, when I used it on a dagger I had enchanted (or maybe cursed) at the anvil, it just disappeared, giving me nothing in return. Thinking it was a bug, I have loaded the game a few times and repeated it, with the same results. The same thing happened when I (accidentally) used it on a Horadric Lutefisk Cube.

Is this behavior erroneous? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happened to me too, when trying on an item with a negative modifier and not a lot of positive modifiers. I don't think it's a bug - I think that this is what happens when the item is just too crappy :)

Comment: Oh, BUT IT'S STILL RARE! :D  (Dammit, the only reason I used that anvil was to get EXP. So I'll just keep the sword, it still is the best one I have. :)